# Use case of System#identityHashCode

Tags: java

Here is a code:

```
Object o = new Object();
System.out.println(o.hashCode());
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(o));
```

The output is similar in both syso so I want to ask if there any use case of `System#identityHashCode` except using it as method reference? The reason why I am concerned about it is because java has similar pattern methods in it.

Comment: [The javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode-java.lang.Object-) answers your question. In case you have trouble understanding it : it disregards the class' hashcode implementation and use the default one instead.

Comment: Lots of classes override `hashCode()` to be compatible with value-based equality. So if you have a use-case where you want a hashcode more consistent with identity-based equality, you might use `System.identityHashCode`

Comment: @khelwood So it means that `o.hashCode()` and `System.identityHashCode(o)` might return different values in some circumstances right?

Comment: Yes, if `o` was a member of some other class, not a `new Object()`.

Comment: @khelwood Got it. Thanks

Comment: Here's an example : https://ideone.com/Ag3V8T

Comment: Thanks @Aaron, that's very helpful in visualizing it :)